# Regular expression to find a word after multiple spaces

Tags: python, regex, text

I am trying to find a word after another word in a text file. I am able to find the word if it is followed by 'one' space. That is

```
string = 'I love my world of dreams'
print re.findall (r'(?<=my)[^ -.]*', string)
```

This gives my output as

```
[world].
```

But if there is more than one space or multiple spaces after word "my" like,

```
string = 'I love my        world of dreams'
```

This will return me only ' '. I want to skip all spaces and find the next word after word "my".

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov - Its not working man .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\s+` (match all whitspaces) or `' +'` but as look-behind requires fixed-width pattern you need to put it outside the look-behind and use grouping  also you can just use `re.search`:
:

```
>>> string = 'I love my           world of dreams'
>>> print re.search (r'(?<=my)\s+([^ -.]*)', string).group(1)
world
```

or

```
>>> string = 'I love my           world of dreams'
>>> print re.search (r'(?<=my) +([^ -.]*)', string).group(1)
world
```

Comment: Does python support infinite repetitions inside lookbehind?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov yep its a typo , i edit the answer, thanks for attentions

Answer (score 0):

Lookbehinds can't have infinite length matches. You'll have to match the whole thing after `my` and extract the subgroup:

```
my\s*([^ -.]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/u29mXaln2pRFoICc)

Answer (score 0):

Try fileinput to read lines in file. Say each line of a file is stored in a string str123. Now following code will help you ...

```
>>>
>>> str123 = ' This is a very long  space in the text'
>>> pqr123 = str123.split()

>>>
>>> nextword = ''
>>> for i in range(len(pqr123)):
...     nextword = pqr123[i]
...     print ('nextword :'+ nextword + '\n')
...
nextword :This

nextword :is

nextword :a

nextword :very

nextword :long

nextword :space

nextword :in

nextword :the

nextword :text

>>>
```

The string ' This is a very long  space in the text' has 2 spaces between **long** and **space**.